# Python converting letter to two-digit number

Tags: python

little noob in Python here.
I'm doing a small personal project and I would want to convert a simple string

```
str='test"
```

to something like that:

```
['20', '05', '19', '20']
```

which would equal to 'test' in two-digit numbers. I found the 'ord' method, but it seems to convert the numbers in integer format and leave them with only one digit where it is not necessary to have two. However for my project I **need those two digits and not in integer format** (it's a DTMF message encoder/decoder that works with a 01-99 range of codes, which equals to one letter/symbol per number).

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you could use `string.ascii_lowercase.index`. Also, the way to get two digits is to convert the int to a string, and then use `.zfill(2)`.

Comment: try ord() to convert characters to numbers and str back to string. remember, ord('a') is 97. so you have to subtract 96 from it to get 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this.

updated code:

```
[f'{ord(i)-96:02d}' for i in 'test'.lower()]
```

earlier code:

```
["{:02d}".format((ord(i)-96)) for i in 'test']
```

This will result in:

```
['20', '05', '19', '20']
```

The above code uses [.format](https://pyformat.info/) option, [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/), and [ord() function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/ord)  Please go through them. Links attached.

Comment: you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) rather than .format here too `f"{ord(c)-96:02d}"`, and you'll want to call `.lower()` if you're subtracting 96: `[f'{ord(c)-96:02d}' for c in 'tEsT'.lower()]`. Alternatively you could use a mask to keep the lowest 5 bits and not call `.lower()`: `[f'{ord(c)&0b11111:02d}' for c in 'tEsT']`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this with `zfill` and get the index from ascii_lowercase (as suggested in the comments) though it's a bit messy. Doing this with `ord and string formatting` is surely the elegant way as Joe answered.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as al
[str(al.index(x)+1).zfill(2) for x in "test"] # ['20', '05', '19', '20']
```

Well, we can use caching with dict for faster look up like below:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as al
cache = {char: idx+1 for idx, char in enumerate(al)}
[str(cache[x]).zfill(2) for x in "test"] # ['20', '05', '19', '20']
```

Comment: this solution slower than it needs to be, index is going to search the list from start to end. You'd be better off building a `dict` first if you wanted to do lookups.

Comment: yeah absolutely. this is pretty inefficient in terms of caching. And even if i create the dict that will have the overhead of creating the object in the first place.